# SQL Best delete record way

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-data

Which one is the best way to delete records from DB?

Using Spring JDBC 3.1.1

```
String SQL="DELETE FROM XXX WHERE USERNAME=?";
```

**Query 1:**

```
getJdbcTemplate().execute(SQL, new PreparedStatementCallback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
               ps.setString(1, username);
               return ps.execute();
            }
         });
```

**Query 2:**

```
int deletedRecordSize = getJdbcTemplate().update(SQL, username);
```

Answer (score 0):

As `DELETE` is an data changing operation you should call `executeUpdate` in your first Query anyway. This would then return `int` as well reducing the difference to length and readability of code.

In which case **Query 2** looks shorter & cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this try catch block inside ur deleting method:

```
try{
                String SQL="DELETE FROM XXX WHERE USERNAME=?";
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql); //conn here is the usual object fro DB connection class

                ps.setString(1, username);
                ps.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"DONE DELETING", "DONE",1);
          }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){

       }
```

Comment: What is the comparison between Query 1 and Query 2 ? Why I need to choice Query 1?

Comment: if you want to make the actual deleting action use first query.
and the style I posted is also common

Comment: what is the meaning of actual deleting? Does it contain special operation?

Comment: I meant by actual deleting is as u set on sql DB and make (delete from) command

Answer (score 0):

I think both are the same according to the link

http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-JdbcTemplate-tutorial

[image]